# Google Script - Wrong month in date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I have a problem with the date recognition of Google Apps Script. I have a code where I need to add days to a given date. However, the code returns the wrong month (higher not lower what would be a typical GAS problem). I wrote the following code to test the behaviour:

```
 var datumStart = new Date();
 datumStart = arrayTimesheet[5][7];
 var datum2 = new Date();
 datum2.setDate(datumStart.getDate());
```

and I receive the following results for the two variables:

```
datumStart   Date   Mon Feb 17 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
datum2       Date   Tue Mar 17 2020 22:50:39 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

the `Array[5][7]` is the value of a Google Sheets cell with the value `2020-17-02`.

This `datum2` variable is just a test variable to understand the error.

Has anybody an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: BTW [mcve] is the minimum amount of code so that we can run the code to produce the same error. Not so minimal that it's nearly impossible to figure what your trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascripts [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) functions get and set the Day of the month.

So, your code is behaving as expected, you are instantiating the date datum2 in March, so it is a date in March (current date/time), later, you use setDate() to set it to the 17th of March.

To add days to a date, you can instantiate a new date using values from your existing date, plus the additional days, eg here we are getting a date 5 days in the future:

```
   var future_day = new Date(datumStart.getFullYear(),datumStart.getMonth(),datum.getDate()+5);
```

Note that Javascript's underlying Date logic is solid, if your number of days crosses a month or year boundary, the results will be correct. (for example, if you add 31 days, you'll get the correct date in the following month)